# how to store values from a .csv file as numbers in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have a .csv file which looks like below:

```
A,3
B,2
C,5
D,1
```

I want to store the above values in a dictionary where an alphabet is the key. My code is below:

```
reader11 = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
for row in reader11:
   if row and row[0]:
      excount[row[0]]=[i for i in row[1] if i]
print excount.items()
```

`excount` is:

```
[('A', ['3']), ('B', ['2']), ('C', ['5']), ('D', ['1'])]
```

The numbers are stored as strings in `excount`. How do I store them as numbers(like below)?

```
[('A', [3]), ('B', [2]), (C, [5]), ('D', [1])]
```

Comment: You should check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091387/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a string to the built-in `int()` function to turn it into a number. Something like this could work:

```
excount[row[0]] = [int(i) for i in row[1] if i]
```

For more about the `int` function, refer to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).