# Python - reading file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Key1    Key2    Key3
Val1-A  Val2-A  Val3-A
Val1-B  Val2-B  Val3-B
....
```

Each field is separated by tab, how can I read the file and store it in a dictionary of lists without using any kind of for/while loop? Comprehensions are allowed

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as input:
    #comprehension here
```

Thanks!

EDIT: sorry I forgot to include my attempt so far

```
 try:
    with open("file.txt", "r") as input:
        line = input.readline()
        line = re.split(r '\t+', line)
        myDict = dict(line.strip() for line in infile)
        if line == "":
            raise ValueError            
 except IOError:
    print ("Error! File is not found.")
 except ValueError:
    print("Error! File is empty.")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dictionary from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091387/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Comment: Also sounds like homework. Please show what you've tried. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer the solutions for that one uses loops, I am looking for a solution that doesn't use one

Comment: @AdamBrinded yes it is a HW, sorry! I included my attempt

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  You should fix those and repost the fixed code. Or ask specific question(s) about the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are two possible solutions which structure the data similar to what you described:

```
data = [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [dict(zip(data[0], i)) for i in data[1:]]
```

Output:

```
[{'Key3': 'Val3-A', 'Key2': 'Val2-A', 'Key1': 'Val1-A'}, {'Key3': 'Val3-B', 'Key2': 'Val2-B', 'Key1': 'Val1-B'}]
```

Or:

```
new_data = {a:list(b) for a, b in zip(data[0], zip(*data[1:]))}
```

Output:

```
{'Key3': ['Val3-A', 'Val3-B'], 'Key2': ['Val2-A', 'Val2-B'], 'Key1': ['Val1-A', 'Val1-B']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as input:
    keys = input.readline().split()
    values = [line.split() for line in input.readlines()]
    result = dict(zip(keys, zip(*values)))
```